# RewriteRule works in a strange way

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In a directory `$HOME/public_html/test` there are two files `.htaccess` and `query.cgi`. I want to convert `xxx.cgi?yyy` into `query.cgi?a=xxx&yyy`.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.cgi\?(.*)$ query.cgi?a=$1&$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.cgi$       query.cgi?b=$1
```

query.cgi (CGI to check the query):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $query = $ENV{QUERY_STRING} ||= "no query";
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
print "<html><body><p>". $query . "</p></body></html>";
```

The problem is: if I access `xxx.cgi?yyy`, then the query is `b=query`.

I expected that the first rule is applied, so that the query is `a=xxx&yyy`. But the first rule is ignored and the second rule is applied, although the second rule can not be applied because of the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to take in to account is that the query string is not part of the match, but stored in its own, separate, variable called `QUERY_STRING`. As you are using in your script. So you need to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/query\.cgi$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.cgi$ /query.cgi?a=$1 [QSA]
```

With the `[QSA]` flag which says append to the query string instead of overwriting.